# Print Clock on all faces of three js cube

Tags: javascript, three.js

How to print current date and time on all faces of a three.js (r84) cube in a specific format using moment.js. Format of the Date&time would be something like this

```
moment().format('dddd') + " " + moment().format('h:mm:ss a') + " " + moment().format('LL');
```

Hours, minutes, seconds and date should increase just like digital clock. Function is as follows:

```
    this.createScene1 = function(scene, data, update) {
    update = update || 0;
    var dynamicTextures = [];
    dynamicTextures.push(_this.dynamicTextureForFaceTextAndImage(data['text1_margin_line_height'][0],data['text1_margin_line_height'][1],data['text1_bold'],data['text1_italic'],data['text1_align'],data['text1_font'],data['text1_font_size'],data['text1_font_color'],data['text1'],data['image1'],data['cube_color']));
    dynamicTextures.push(_this.dynamicTextureForFaceTextAndImage(data['text2_margin_line_height'][0],data['text2_margin_line_height'][1],data['text2_bold'],data['text2_italic'],data['text2_align'],data['text2_font'],data['text2_font_size'],data['text2_font_color'],data['text2'],data['image2'],data['cube_color']));
    dynamicTextures.push(_this.dynamicTextureForFaceTextAndImage(data['text3_margin_line_height'][0],data['text3_margin_line_height'][1],data['text3_bold'],data['text3_italic'],data['text3_align'],data['text3_font'],data['text3_font_size'],data['text3_font_color'],data['text3'],data['image3'],data['cube_color']));
    dynamicTextures.push(_this.dynamicTextureForFaceTextAndImage(data['text4_margin_line_height'][0],data['text4_margin_line_height'][1],data['text4_bold'],data['text4_italic'],data['text4_align'],data['text4_font'],data['text4_font_size'],data['text4_font_color'],data['text4'],data['image4'],data['cube_color']));
    dynamicTextures.push(_this.dynamicTextureForFaceTextAndImage(data['text5_margin_line_height'][0],data['text5_margin_line_height'][1],data['text5_bold'],data['text5_italic'],data['text5_align'],data['text5_font'],data['text5_font_size'],data['text5_font_color'],data['text5'],data['image5'],data['cube_color']));
    dynamicTextures.push(_this.dynamicTextureForFaceTextAndImage(data['text6_margin_line_height'][0],data['text6_margin_line_height'][1],data['text6_bold'],data['text6_italic'],data['text6_align'],data['text6_font'],data['text6_font_size'],data['text6_font_color'],data['text6'],data['image6'],data['cube_color']));
    var text = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < dynamicTextures.length; i++) {
        text.push(new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
            ambient: 0xffffff,
            map: dynamicTextures[i].texture
        }))
    }


    if (update == 1) {
        scene.remove(_this.cube);
    }


    var geo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(data['cube_width'],data['cube_height'],data['cube_depth']); // w, h, d
    _this.cube = new THREE.Mesh(geo, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(text));
    //var cube    = new THREE.Mesh( geo, materialText );
    _this.cube.name = "scene-1-lambert-cube";
    scene.add(_this.cube);

}
```

Clock value/variable will be replaced by data['text1'] parameter.

Comment: You can start from [here](http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2014/05/02/easy-to-use-dynamic-texture-to-write-text-in-your-3d-object-with-threex-dot-dynamictexture-game-extensions-for-three-dot-js/)

Comment: @prisoner849 thankyou so much.